# How to extract prefix from URI?

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there approach that assembles prefix:local-name of an element by given URN and a local-name?

For example using this code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xstible:1.0" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
        <xsl:element name="element" namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xstible:1.0">
            <nested-element>Some text...</nested-element>
        </xsl:element>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I get as result is:

```
<root xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xstible:1.0">
    <element xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xstible:1.0">
        <nested-element xmlns="">Some text...</nested-element>
    </element>
</root>
```

What I want as a result is:

```
<root xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xstible:1.0">
    <fo:element>
        <nested-element>Some text...</nested-element>
    </fo:element>
</root>
```

Giving the URI to the xsl:element, the name to be magically prefixed (with the prefix that corresponds to that URI - declared in the root element), and the URI absent into the result document. I hope you understand what I am trying to achieve :)

Comment: In your wanted result, the `nested-element` element is in no-namespace. Are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: Yes. I use literal for my root element so it can hold all namespace declarations.

Comment: OK. I don't think you can tell your XSLT processor to add a prefix automatically the way you describe. Perhaps you could do this in two passes, and handle the unprefixed elements on the second pass. In any case, the results are semantically identical, so there is no good reason to spend any effort on this.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you have a reason to explicitly use `<xsl:element />` rather than simply declaring the `<fo:element>` element directly.

The [XSLT 1.0 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) allows the `<xsl:element />` `@name` attribute [to be a **qname**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl:element). Therefore you can reuse an already declared namespace by prepending its prefix to the element *@name* in the usual way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xstible:1.0" 
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:element name="fo:element">
                <nested-element>Some text...</nested-element>
            </xsl:element>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XSLT 1.0 processor will safe check that the prefix has been declared.

Code tested in Saxon 6.5.5.